# Building a sentinel Node using templates - C++

Tags: c++, tree

I am currently trying to implement a RB-tree in C++ using templates. I've got 2 classes - one is rB.h (where there are all the functions needed such as insert and delete to provide functionality for the tree), another is node.h(which consists of the basic attributes of the node and the corresponding getter/setter functions to provide for encapsulation). I would like to declare a node called 'sentinel'. The function of the sentinel node is so that each node which has a NULL pointer (i.e. left/right child does not exist) points to the sentinel. Furthermore, the sentinel's colour should be black. I am unsure as to how this should be declared since I am using templates and am quite new to both C++ and templates altogether. Below is some of the code for my node.h (basically the private variables and the constructor). I did not include the entire class so I won't have many lines of code. Could anyone offer any guidelines?

```
template<class T, class key>

class Node {
private:
    Node<T,key>*left;
    Node<T,key>*right;
    Node<T,key>*parent;
    key k;
    T value;
    string colour;

public:

    Node<T,key>* root;


    Node(T value,key k,Node<T,key>*l, Node<T,key>*r, Node<T,key>*p, string c){
        setLeft(l);
        setRight(r);
        setParent(p);
        setKey(k);
        setValue(value);
        setColour(c);
    }

   //all getters and setters


};
```

Comment: Why do you think this is better than using a nullptr? i.e. how is this going to reduce code, make things faster, etc?

Comment: I need to ensure that the colour of the node is black (i.e. all those nodes which do not have left/right children must point to a node, called the sentinel node, which is of a black colour). Simply assigning them to a nullptr will not enable me to do this.

Comment: off topic, but using an enum for `colour` might be better suited

Answer (score 0):

For a sentinel node you'd probably use a `static` member function of you class template which provides access to a pointer to a `static` variable:

```
template <typename T, typename Key>
Node<T, Key> const* Node<T, Key>::sentinel() {
    static Node<T,Key> rc(...);
    return &rc;
}
```